# MongoClient connection establishment getting timed out from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda

I'm looking to execute my handler function from `AWS Lambda`. In my local system code works fine but the `MongoClient` connection establishment is getting timed out every time from `AWS Lambda`.

`Error`: `2019-12-13T05:59:21.925Z 15e6fc4c-c630-4ea9-a225-3fbb654d6b32 Task timed out after 15.01 seconds`

This is how I'm establishing connection to `MongoDB` servers:

```
const connection = await MongoClient.connect(mongoDBURL);
```

I've also tried `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` in the handler function but no luck!

`Edit`: I tried increasing the `Lambda Timeout` to 30 seconds but still it's same.

Comment: Is your lambda function inside the default VPC, or custom VPC with configured with Nat? I guess what im trying to say is, have you tested to make sure your Lambda function has internet access?

Comment: Also, is your lambda VCP static ip address whitelisted by your mongo instance, or are you allowing access to all traffic by your mongo instance?

Comment: @EphHarris There are some older APIs written in java which are deployed in lambda and accessing the same mongoDB. So I think VPC is not the issue.